# GraphDB free stops working

Tags: graphdb

I'm using GraphDB Free 8.4.1 in research project and sometimes it gets stucked without any obvious reason. Process is running, but it is not possible to connect to repository, not even from workbench. It just stops responding.

I have to kill the GraphDB and then run it again.

I'm aware, that free edition allows only 2 queries in parallel, but i would not expect it would get stucked. I tried to reproduce this by making 30 parallel SPARQL queries, but everything worked ok.

There is no exception, nothing in error log, nothing in main log.

Please, where could be the problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can diagnose the problem by running jstack on the GraphDB process. This will give us details about the process activity.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Pls, how can I do it? This is new for me. The instance is running at remote server and this issue arises time to time, unpredictably, I have no idea why, so I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: jstack graphdb_pid > jstack.txt in linux or simply copy the output in a text file.

Comment: thank you, i will do it as soon as it happens again. is there some other info that will help to diagnose problem i can provide? when it happens i will need to restart the triplestore asap, as it is in prototype production.

Comment: My supposition is that the problem is related to memory configuration, but I cannot be sure without any stack trace. If you have additional environment (not production due to license issues) you can enable profiler on the Java process and examine it after. Note that this can affect the performance by 5-10% and you can use it only in dev and staging environments.
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=dumponexit=true,filename=prof.jfr